# Get MAC address on local machine with Java

Tags: java, sockets, mac-address

I can use

```
ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
```

to obtain the mac address, but if I use this code in an offline machine it doesn't work.

So, **How can I get the Mac address?**

Comment: Technically, you should treat an offline machine as though it has no network card anyway. How do you deal with that latter case?

Comment: Why does your program need this information?  What benefit does it provide to the end user?

Comment: And what if the machine has more than one? And are you aware that the MAC address can be changed by the user? There is nothing you can do with a MAC address in Java except try to use it as a machine identifier, which it is not adequate for.

Comment: thanks, I try to use it as a machine identifier, so What is the proper way to identify a machine in java?

Comment: You try to use it as a machine identifier even though it can't be used as a machine identifier?

Comment: @EJP what is your proposal for this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With Java 6+, you can use [`NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()).

Bear in mind that a computer can have no network cards, especially if it's embedded or virtual. It can also have more than one. You can get a list of all network cards with [`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()).

Comment: I had an issue, that I on some computers only got a truncated, 4-byte mac-address. I managed to solve this by including -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true as startup parameter for java

Answer (score 27):

With all the possible solutions that i've found here and another replies, then i will contribute with my solution. You need to specify a parameter with a String containing "ip" or "mac" depending on what you need to check. If the computer has no interface, then it will return an String containing null, otherwise will return a String containing what you asked for (the ip address or the mac).

How to use it:

```
System.out.println("Ip: " + GetNetworkAddress.GetAddress("ip"));
System.out.println("Mac: " + GetNetworkAddress.GetAddress("mac"));
```

Result (if the computer has a network card):

```
Ip: 192.168.0.10 
Mac: 0D-73-ED-0A-27-44
```

Result (if the computer doesn't have a network card):

```
Ip: null
Mac: null
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class GetNetworkAddress {

    public static String GetAddress(String addressType) {
        String address = "";
        InetAddress lanIp = null;
        try {

            String ipAddress = null;
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> net = null;
            net = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

            while (net.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface element = net.nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = element.getInetAddresses();

                while (addresses.hasMoreElements() && element.getHardwareAddress().length > 0 && !isVMMac(element.getHardwareAddress())) {
                    InetAddress ip = addresses.nextElement();
                    if (ip instanceof Inet4Address) {

                        if (ip.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                            ipAddress = ip.getHostAddress();
                            lanIp = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            if (lanIp == null)
                return null;

            if (addressType.equals("ip")) {

                address = lanIp.toString().replaceAll("^/+", "");

            } else if (addressType.equals("mac")) {

                address = getMacAddress(lanIp);

            } else {

                throw new Exception("Specify \"ip\" or \"mac\"");

            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return address;

    }

    private static String getMacAddress(InetAddress ip) {
        String address = null;
        try {

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            address = sb.toString();

        } catch (SocketException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return address;
    }

    private static boolean isVMMac(byte[] mac) {
        if(null == mac) return false;
        byte invalidMacs[][] = {
                {0x00, 0x05, 0x69},             //VMWare
                {0x00, 0x1C, 0x14},             //VMWare
                {0x00, 0x0C, 0x29},             //VMWare
                {0x00, 0x50, 0x56},             //VMWare
                {0x08, 0x00, 0x27},             //Virtualbox
                {0x0A, 0x00, 0x27},             //Virtualbox
                {0x00, 0x03, (byte)0xFF},       //Virtual-PC
                {0x00, 0x15, 0x5D}              //Hyper-V
        };

        for (byte[] invalid: invalidMacs){
            if (invalid[0] == mac[0] && invalid[1] == mac[1] && invalid[2] == mac[2]) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

UPDATED 02/05/2017: Thanks to @mateuscb on the post [How to Determine Internet Network Interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462498/how-to-determine-internet-network-interface-in-java) that unfortunately didn't get any upvote on that post before, but he contributed to this update.

The method has been improved to skip virtual machine network cards (most popular VM software)

Comment: What do I do if this gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception at `if (invalid[0] == mac[0] && invalid[1] == mac[1] && invalid[2] == mac[2]) return true;`?

Comment: @Sumit check the number of items that are in both arrays "invalid" and "mac" because one of them or both have less than three items

Comment: So I found another piece of code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449379/3169868 which shows the first MAC address as blank and remaining 3 (including VMs). Can this code be modified to handle this?

Comment: @Sumit try replacing this line `while (addresses.hasMoreElements() && !isVMMac(element.getHardwareAddress())) {` by `while (addresses.hasMoreElements() && element.getHardwareAddress().length > 0 && !isVMMac(element.getHardwareAddress())) {`

Comment: Thanks, works fine now! Perhaps you may consider updating the sample code in the answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

As for the computer being offline, it usually doesn't have an IP assigned, because DHCP is widely used...

And for the question in the title:
[`NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final NetworkInterface netInf = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().nextElement();
final byte[] mac = netInf.getHardwareAddress();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
}
log.info("Mac addr: {}", sb.toString());
```

Comment: There are some exceptions you should catch.

Comment: for me getHardwareAddress gave null. Any idea why? I am running in just a laptop. No VM or any aws or azure instance

Comment: getInetAddresses().nextElement() gives /127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up code from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/):

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class HardwareAddress
{
    public static String getMacAddress() throws UnknownHostException,
            SocketException
    {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface
                .getByInetAddress(ipAddress);
        byte[] macAddressBytes = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
        StringBuilder macAddressBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int macAddressByteIndex = 0; macAddressByteIndex < macAddressBytes.length; macAddressByteIndex++)
        {
            String macAddressHexByte = String.format("%02X",
                    macAddressBytes[macAddressByteIndex]);
            macAddressBuilder.append(macAddressHexByte);

            if (macAddressByteIndex != macAddressBytes.length - 1)
            {
                macAddressBuilder.append(":");
            }
        }

        return macAddressBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an OS command 'getmac' through native code execution.

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getmac /fo csv /nh");
    java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new  java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    line = in.readLine();        
    String[] result = line.split(",");

    System.out.println(result[0].replace('"', ' ').trim());
```

Comment: `getmac` is available only on Windows. But not on Ubuntu 13.10 (nor with `apt-get`) and Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

> Medium access control address ([MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address))

MAC address of a device is a unique identifier assigned to a network interface controller (NIC). For communications within a network segment, it is used as a network address for most IEEE 802 network technologies, including Ethernet, Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth. Within the Open Systems Interconnection ([OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) model, MAC addresses are used in the medium access control protocol sublayer of the data link layer.

MAC addresses are most often assigned by the manufacturer of network interface cards. Each is stored in hardware, such as the card's read-only memory or by a firmware mechanism.

Use the following function **`getPhysicalAddress()`** to get list of MAC address:

```java
static String format = "%02X"; // To get 2 char output.
private static String[] getPhysicalAddress() throws Exception{
    try {
        // DHCP Enabled - InterfaceMetric
        Set<String> macs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while( nis.hasMoreElements() ) {
            NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
            byte mac [] = ni.getHardwareAddress(); // Physical Address (MAC - Medium Access Control)
            if( mac != null ) {
                final StringBuilder macAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    macAddress.append(String.format("%s"+format, (i == 0) ? "" : ":", mac[i]) );
                    //macAddress.append(String.format(format+"%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? ":" : ""));
                }
                System.out.println(macAddress.toString());
                macs.add( macAddress.toString() );
            }
        }
        return macs.toArray( new String[0] );
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        System.err.println( "Exception:: " + ex.getMessage() );
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Host/System Name : "+ localHost.getHostName());
    System.out.println("Host IP Address  : "+ localHost.getHostAddress());

    String macs2 [] = getPhysicalAddress();
    for( String mac : macs2 )
        System.err.println( "MacAddresses = " + mac );
}
```

The above function works as [**`ipconfig`**](https://www.computerhope.com/ipconfig.htm)`/all|find "Physical Address"  >>MV-mac.txt`.

```
D:\>ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address"
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-57-A6-00-0C-BB
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 01-FF-60-93-0B-88
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 62-B8-9A-2B-F3-87
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-B8-9A-2B-F3-87
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-B8-9A-2B-F3-87
```

The [IEEE divides the OSI data link layer](https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/documents/tutorials/macgrp.pdf) into two separate sublayers:

- Logical link control (LLC): Transitions up to the network layer
- MAC: Transitions down to the physical layer <sup>[Image ref](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2092245&seqNum=2)</sup>

---

> [getmac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/getmac)

Returns the media access control (MAC) address and list of network protocols associated with each address for all network cards in each computer, either locally or across a network.

```
D:\>getmac /fo csv /nh
```

---

> [NET START](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/236166/using-net-stop-and-net-start-commands-to-force-iis-services-to-re-read) command

```
D:\>netsh interface ipv4 show addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    .asSequence()
    .mapNotNull { ni ->
        ni.hardwareAddress?.joinToString(separator = "-") {
            "%02X".format(it)
        }
    }.toList()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        InetAddress ip;
        try {

            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }
```

output:

```
Current IP address : 192.168.21.60
Current MAC address : 70-5A-0F-3C-84-F2
```

Comment: This is exactly what the original post said *doesn't* work for an offline computer.