# how to get machines mac address

Tags: java

I want get machines' MAC address..but below written code only display the MAC address when Internet is connected to my machine other it will return null... I am using windows 7

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InetAddress ip;
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            System.out.println("The mac Address of this machine is :" + ip.getHostAddress());

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("The mac address is : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++){
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i],(i< mac.length - 1)?"-":""));
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to start indenting your code. Right now it's pretty hard to read due to the lack of indentation!

Comment: What happens if your box is not connected to the internet? What's the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MAC address on local machine with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164167/get-mac-address-on-local-machine-with-java)

Comment: Its worth noting that a MAC address can be changed, so it may not do what you want. Why do you want it?

Comment: @home: It will return null....

Comment: @peterLawrey:I am developing one Application...But My condition is.. it will run only on one machine .I need Any Permanent Address of Machine.

Comment: I don't believe such a thing exists (which cannot be bypassed)

Comment: It run successfully on my computer..i am also using window 7.

Answer (score 6):

Try this **it should work in both Linux and windows**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String command = "/sbin/ifconfig";

    String sOsName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (sOsName.startsWith("Windows")) {
        command = "ipconfig";
    } else {

        if ((sOsName.startsWith("Linux")) || (sOsName.startsWith("Mac"))
                || (sOsName.startsWith("HP-UX"))) {
            command = "/sbin/ifconfig";
        } else {
            System.out.println("The current operating system '" + sOsName
                    + "' is not supported.");
        }
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("([a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}(-|:)){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}");
    try {
        Process pa = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        pa.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                pa.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        Matcher m;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            m = p.matcher(line);

            if (!m.find())
                continue;
            line = m.group();
            break;

        }
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you are trying to get the MAC address by IP address. An IP address exists *only* when you are connected *successfully* to the Internet. Otherwise, it will be `null`, as you state.

Try this: [`NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()).

If you want the MAC address of all network interfaces on your computer, try this: [`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()).

---

**EDIT**: After reviewing the code again, I realize that you have my suggestion implemented. However, you are only trying to obtain the MAC address **if** you have a valid IP. You will not have a valid IP if are not connected to the Internet.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
       NetworkInterface network;
       byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();  
       System.out.print("The mac address is : ");  

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

       for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
       { 
         sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i],(i< mac.length - 1)?"-":"")); 
       }     

       System.out.println(sb.toString());  
   }
```

Comment: NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() does not list NICs which are disconnected. Did you test it?

Comment: @PeterMel It was so long ago, I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably caused by the fact that when your machine isn't connected to the Internet, your network card doesn't have an assigned IP address. And you are trying to look up the network interface by an IP address.

I suggest you to enumerate all network interfaces instead, and pick the one you need:

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {

    protected static String formatMac(byte[] mac) {
        if (mac == null)
            return "UNKNOWN";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       for(Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e
                    = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
               e.hasMoreElements(); )
       {
           NetworkInterface ni = e.nextElement();
           System.out.println(ni.getName() + " - " + formatMac(ni.getHardwareAddress()));
       }
   }
}
```

This should solve the problem and work without any Internet connection.

Comment: This also does not work when the nic is disconnected! :(