# How to get MAC address by java with offline state

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, mac-address

I'm trying to get the MAC address of my PC without connecting to the internet,
I used this code

```
InetAddress ip;
try {
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 

    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
    }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

} catch (UnknownHostException | SocketException e) {
}
```

it works when my computer is connected to internet, but when i go offline it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get machines mac address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884696/how-to-get-machines-mac-address)

Comment: please refer to  the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164167/get-mac-address-on-local-machine-with-java

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for getting mac address for your PC even if it is not connected to internet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        final byte [] mac = e.nextElement().getHardwareAddress();
        if (mac != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Many machines have multiple Mac Addresses as well. So this might return you multiple Mac Addresses