# Get MAC Address of System in Java

Tags: java

I need to get the mac address of the system running the program. But I am not able to do that.

I am writing following code:

```
public class App{

       public static void main(String[] args){

        InetAddress ip;
        try {

            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }

    }
```

And I am getting following results:

```
 Current IP address : 14.96.192.202
 Current MAC address :
```

I am not getting the MAC Address it is blank.

I saw this example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/)

Comment: It is showing NULL in the output..!

Comment: Windows or Linux? Might need to make sure program is running as admin?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you account for multiple interfaces, and some null MAC addresses (I'm running Java 7 on Windows 7 with VMWare installed (so I have some virtual network adapters)) then this code seems to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networks = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(networks.hasMoreElements()) {
      NetworkInterface network = networks.nextElement();
      byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

      if(mac != null) {
        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
          sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
      }
    }
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SocketException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Here is (a sanitized version of) what I see on my computer when I run it:

```
Current IP address : {I'm not telling :)}
Current MAC address : 
Current MAC address : {actual hardware interface}
Current MAC address : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
Current MAC address : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
Current MAC address : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
Current MAC address : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
Current MAC address : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
Current MAC address : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
Current MAC address : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
```

And here is the output of running `ipconfig /all`

```
C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration (minus any actual interface because I don't like sharing that kind of information :)

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Gbridge Virtual Private Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-50-F2-CE-82-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9c27:3d03:da2c:f14d%19(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : {Hidden}(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268456022
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-DB-D9-CB-B8-AC-6F-AF-9D-F2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cdbb:434:7fd9:2574%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 285233238
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-DB-D9-CB-B8-AC-6F-AF-9D-F2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:204c:1bc6::204c:1bc6(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3E45CB42-BC1E-4F89-9C16-25166C0EABA1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{77F1FADC-02BA-44AF-9FDF-97E23F8B5FE7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{608257AC-C0F3-43A5-8595-898533C95D90}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The challenge in getting "just one value" from this mess comes from the relationship between `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` and the network interfaces themselves.  Consider this slight expanded version of the initial program (using this really cool [IterableEnumeration](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html) utility class):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException {
  System.out.println("Current IP address : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());

  for(NetworkInterface network : IterableEnumeration.make(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
    if(mac != null) {
      System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
      }
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
      //Bound InetAddress for interface
      for(InetAddress address : IterableEnumeration.make(network.getInetAddresses())) {
        System.out.println("\tBound to:"+address.getHostAddress());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this on your computer you will see your current IP address correlates to one adapter but that MAC address of your hardware interface sees it's self as a different IP address.  Maybe you can filter out virtual addresses or just find a way to utilize all available addresses.

Comment: it returns a set of values. but I just need a single Value for my program. Then how would I take just one value. and that too appropriate.

Comment: I took a stab at adding to my answer.