# How to write request.getRemoteHost() method in servlet init() method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to write request.getRemoteHost() method in servlet init() method?

eg:

```
public void init() throws ServletException
{
    String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
    System.out.println("----------");
    System.out.println("------ ServletInitializer Servlet Initialized successfully ------");
    System.out.println("----------remoteHost :"+remoteHost);
}
```

Comment: `init()` method doesn't have any httprequest object. It's made for `doGet()` or `doPost()` when actual request is made from the client.

Comment: As per your comment you are interested to get the mac address. have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448995/get-mac-address-of-system-in-java) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getRemoteHost()
```

inside `init()` doesnt make any sense

Please understand init method is called during the initialization of the servlet and not for the every request.

So you could handle it in the post/get methods. `init()` is not request dependent .

**Update:**

```
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

gets the `IP` of the client . but you cant use it in the `init()` function as explained above use it in the `doPost()` or `doGet()` where you have implemented other methods

Comment: I want to get the Mac Id while starting the Tomcat

Comment: so you want to ip of the system where the server resides or application is deployed.

Comment: As per your question "you cant write request.getParameter() inside init()" because init() doesnt have the request object . update your question with proper details and clearly show us what you need

Comment: In my online project i need the IP Address of the client while he is trying to open this site

Comment: see my update in the answer

Comment: @user3906140 The request remote address won't give you the MAC address; the MAC address is only useful within its LAN; and it is of no use whatsoever in Java except as a very low grade system identifier string.