# How to Determine appropriate MAC address using Java

Tags: java, windows, networking, connection, adapter

I'm building an email sending software and user's requirement is, this program would be able to get and change the MAC address of the system. I searched over internet and found how can we get MAC address using java. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448995/get-mac-address-of-system-in-java) I found a sample code that list all MAC addresses of the system. Using this code I have my output like this.

```
Current IP address : 169.254.74.152
Current MAC address : 00-27-10-52-D6-49
Current MAC address : 70-F3-95-82-2A-85
Current MAC address : 0A-00-27-00-00-11
Current MAC address : 0A-00-27-00-00-12
Current MAC address : 00-27-10-52-D6-48
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

This output include MAC addresses of
 1. Wireless LAN adapter WiFi
 2. Wireless LAN adapter Local Area connection
 3. Ethernet adapter Bluetooth
 4. Ethernet adapter Virtual-box

It shows the same output irrespective of whether I'm connected to internet or not. So my question is how can I determine the one I'm connected with i.e. If I'm connected and using WiFi internet I need WiFi MAC and if I'm connected using Network Cable I need that.
And also tell how to change/spoof that MAC address using Java.

Comment: Sounds like a bizarre requirement for an email sending software.

Comment: Java cannot change the MAC address. Send the requirement back for review. It's a control panel operation. Not something that needs to be built into any application.

Answer (score 0):

> It shows the same output irrespective of whether I'm connected to internet or not.

Of course it does. Your local MAC addresses don't change just because you're connected to the Internet.

> So my question is how can I determine the one I'm connected with i.e. If I'm connected and using WiFi internet I need WiFi MAC and if I'm connected using Network Cable I need that.

You need it for what? There is nothing useful you can do with a MAC address in Java except to display it.

> And also tell how to change/spoof that MAC address using Java.

You can't.