# get devices info on local network like fing

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a network scanner on android
Simply I need to get devices information like display name, vendor name  and mac address .
For now with "ping" and "arp" commands on terminal I can find all devices and their mac address on my network but I can't find any way , command or java code to get display name and vendor name.
I searched in google many times for java code, linux commands ,Tried android NSD and get nothing.
please see this image
[somthing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdjzh.jpg)
Thank you

Comment: you can get device info by MAC address -- http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/

Comment: Great, But is there any way to do it on java or linux commands?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164167/get-mac-address-on-local-machine-with-java

Comment: Thanks @Leo but I need to get name and vendor of other devices on local network

Comment: It seems to me that you're going to try the IPs in your local network, and given this info, you'll get the MAC address, and given the MAC address, you'll get the vendor, isn't it?

Comment: see image in thepost , I want to get display name and vendor name and mac address from ip on local network , now i have a way to get mac address on android with using arp on terminal so finding mac address done. now i need a way to find display name and vendor name , in windows we can use "nbtstat -a ip address" this command gives us display name and workgroup (but it's too slow), so I need something like nbtstat on android to get display name of other devices @leo

Comment: I see. Have you checked this? https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

Comment: I saw this before but I couldn't run it and put it away, now thanks to you I checked it again and find out that for getting vendor name they used database , for hostname they used "InetAddress.getByName(host.ipAddress)).getCanonicalHostName()" , but I tried it many times ,this returns IP Address only. thank you for helping @leo