# How to restrict my exe to get installed only on specific computer?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to restrict my setup, which I made using launch4j, to get installed only on a specific computer. To be specific, I want to get the MAC address of the computer and check if it is that specific computer and then allow it to install the setup(or run exe).

I searched online for it, but I couldn't find any solution

Lang: java
IDE: NetBeans
Executable made by using: Launch4j
setup installer Made by Inno Setup Compiler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164167/get-mac-address-on-local-machine-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possibility that the computer would have no network card or have many of them therefore making MAC address-based recognition error prone.

Retrieving MAC addresses of network interfaces on computer

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();

    System.out.println(networkInterface.getName() + " " +
        networkInterface.getDisplayName());
}
```

The problem of many MAC addresses can be mitigated with hashing the MACs' concatenated string. But there still is an issue of no existing MAC address case.

---

Another possibility of unique identifying of computer is to hash some of it internal specifications, eg processor serial number, processor identifier, operating system, etc. For example by using cross-platform [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) library. This solution is not dependant on existing network adapters on the machine.